# events are fired multiple times in class/object

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, removeeventlistener

To explain the context, i have a div named Repertory who contain divs with class Card, on the instantiation of my class Explorer i use loadDragNDropEvents() who load dragstart and dragend events on cards, when I start a drag i need to make my canvas have over event and drop event (only when a card is drag).

1. Dragstart and dragend are fired twice, how can i fix that ?
   *i already try to do a removeEventListener before the adding one without success*
2. Roughly as above dragover and drop events aren't removed, how can i fix that ?

My code : *(I simplify it to focus on the needs)*

HTML :

```
<div id="Repertory">
  <div class="Card">Card 1</div>
  <div class="Card">Card 2</div>
  <div class="Card">Card 3</div>
  <div class="Card">Card 4</div>
  <div class="Card">Card 5</div>
  <div class="Card">Card 6</div>
</div>

<canvas id="canvas" style="width:100px; height: 100px;"></canvas>
```

JS :

```
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var explorer1 = new Explorer(); // Create an Explorer and use loadDragNDropEvents() 2 times

class Explorer() {

  contructor(){
    loadDragNDropEvents();
    loadDragNDropEvents();
  }

  loadDragNDropEvents() {
    const repertory = document.getElementById("Repertory");
    if (repertory == undefined) { return this; }
        
    const cards = repertory.querySelectorAll(".Card"); 
    if (cards.length <= 0) { return this; }

    console.log("loadDragNDropEvents");

    cards.forEach(card => {
      card.addEventListener("dragstart", this.#CardDragStartEvent.bind(this), false);
      card.addEventListener("dragend", this.#CardDragEndEvent.bind(this), false);
    });
  }

  unloadDragNDropEvents() {
    const repertory = document.getElementById("Repertory");
    if (repertory == undefined) { return this; }
        
    const cards = repertory.querySelectorAll(".Card"); 
    if (cards.length <= 0) { return this; }

    console.log("loadDragNDropEvents");

    cards.forEach(card => {
      card.removeEventListener("dragstart", this.#CardDragStartEvent.bind(this), false);
      card.removeEventListener("dragend", this.#CardDragEndEvent.bind(this), false);
    });
  }

  #CardDragStartEvent(event) {
    console.log("dragstart");
    canvas.addEventListener("dragover", this.#CanvasDragOverEvent.bind(this), false);
    canvas.addEventListener("drop", this.#CanvasDropEvent.bind(this), false);
    event.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = "move";
  }

  #CardDragEndEvent(event) {
    console.log("dragend");
    canvas.removeEventListener("dragover", this.#CanvasDragOverEvent.bind(this), false);
    canvas.removeEventListener("drop", this.#CanvasDropEvent.bind(this), false);
  }

  #CanvasDragOverEvent(event) {
    console.log("over");
    event.preventDefault();
    event.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "move";
  }

  #CanvasDropEvent(event) {
    console.log("drop");
    event.preventDefault();
  }

}
```

thanks by advance

Comment: To avoid the DnD events firing twice remove the second call to `loadDragNDropEvents`.

Comment: When you add the event listeners you're creating a new bound function (via `bind`). When you remove them you create a *new* bound function (via `bind`). Instead, bind them once (likely in the ctor) so you can add and remove the same function.

Comment: @DaveNewton, the second one seems like a good option but i don't understand how i should do it

Comment: I'm not sure how else to explain it. Bind the handlers once, in the ctor, e.g., `this.#CardDragStartEvent = this.#CardDragStartEvent.bind(this)` and use the new reference to for adding and removing the event handler.

Comment: it doesn't work cause, even if I create a var to which I assign my function.bind

Answer (score 0):

I use another method that isn't clean but that work well, I'm always listening if someone can solve my problem.

```
loadDragNDropEvents() {

  this.unloadDragNDropEvents(); // Unload drag and drop events before adding new ones

  const repertory = document.getElementById("Repertory");
  if (repertory == undefined) { return this; }
        
  const cards = repertory.querySelectorAll(".Card"); 
  if (cards.length <= 0) { return this; }

  console.log("loadDragNDropEvents");

  cards.forEach(card => {
    card.addEventListener("dragstart", this.#CardDragStartEvent.bind(this), false);
    card.addEventListener("dragend", this.#CardDragEndEvent.bind(this), false);
  });
}

// Now clone and replace the DOM élément to clea
unloadDragNDropEvents() {

  console.log("unloadDragNDrop");

  let oldRep = document.getElementById("Repertory");
  let newRep = oldRep.cloneNode(true);
  oldRep.parrentNode.replaceChild(newRep, oldRep);
}
```